# Node.js and Jetty 6

Tags: java, jetty, websocket, socket.io

I wanna use node.js and app.js in my application

My application under java programming language and my application container is Jetty 6 server

So can I use node.js and app.js inside my application ?

Answer (score 1):

You wont be able to run node.js inside your servlet container.

However you can write services in node.js and host it along side jetty and have your application consume those services.

i.e your java application connects to a rest service that running on top of node, to perform its database access.

or vice versa.